# Javascript does not work in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

The following JavaScript works on IE7 but not on IE8:

```
onclick=history.back(1) or history.go(-1)
```

Any suggestions on why this is the case and how to overcome it.

Comment: I don't know, but I really wouldn't want you to be doing that anyway. Sites that push me around are evil.

Comment: Is that JavaScript appearing within an HTML attribute? Or is that an assignment to some object property?

Comment: @harto: Same thought here. I would reckon it's an attribute, and the quotes are missing, making IE8 show some of it's new strictness.

Comment: Ideally, using the "history" methods is kinda bad. Describe what you want to do exactly, and we may be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  This is how it is being used in code:
lblmessage.Text += "<br><a href='#' onclick='history.back(1);'> <u>Back</u></a>"

Comment: Why are you using an anchor if you aren't using the href?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried:

```
onclick="history.back()"
```

with the quotes?

---

And, responding to your statement that it doesn't work: *au contraire, mon ami.*

The following two files run fine on my IE8 install, using the files `x1.html`:

```
    <html><head></head><body>
        X1
        <hr>
        <a href="x2.html">x2</a>
    </body></html>
```

and `x2.html`:

```
    <html><head></head><body>
        X2
        <hr>
        <button onclick="history.back()">Back!</button>
    </body></html>
```

When I load `x1`, I can move to `x2` with the link, then the button moves back to `x1`.

This works in all three compatibility modes, ergo it must be a setting on your browser which is affecting this.

One thing I had to do to get this to work was to go to `Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> Security` and select `Allow active content to run in files on My Computer`, so it's almost certainly a security setting in your browser which is causing you grief.

Answer (score 2):

i used this and works well :

```
<asp:Button ID="Back_BTN" runat="server" Text="بازگشت" 
onclientclick="javascript:history.back(1);return false;" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem. Never check its also the same on ie7 or not

Code like below cant run on IE8. Can on FF3.5

```
<select size="2">
<option onclick="alert('hey hey')">Hey hey</option>
<option onclick="alert('a ha')">A Ha</option>
</select>
```

However, this on work

```
<select onclick="alert('uh oh')" size="2">
<option>Hey hey</option>
<option>A Ha</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it like this...

```
 <a href='javascript:history.back(); ' onclick="history.back(); "><input type="button" value="Back" /></a>
```

You need to put history.back() into your a href tag and also the onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

Try history.back(), if that doesn't work then try this history.back();return false;

Answer (score 0):

It may be a simple reversal of quotes. Try this

```
lblmessage.Text += '<br><a href="#" onclick="history.back(1);"> <u>Back</u></a>'
```

instead of this

```
lblmessage.Text += "<br><a href='#' onclick='history.back(1);'> <u>Back</u></a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the answer, but maybe it will help someone else dig up the real answer... The issue might be related to IE8's compatibility mode.  Weird things happen in IE8 based on the DOCTYPE of the web page.  If your DOCTYPE is Transitional, IE8 might not properly handle the onclick event.

Comment: HTML 5 doctype wins. It forces every browser into standards mode.