# Histyr.back() wont work in new window in IE

Tags: javascript, html, window

What I have is a form, which when you press next it moves onto the next step. Now what i want is when the user presses a back button, it takes them to the previous step. But retaining the data in the form fields. I had it working in chrome. BUt when i come to use it in IE, it does not work in a new popup window; if it is in a normal page it does work, but not in a popup window.

Can anyone give me any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript library like [JQuery](http://jquery.com/),[dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) will help this issue And also u need to look at this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/754953/1862502)

Comment: OK i will try that thanks, all of the solutions in the other post I have tried already. It isn't the fact that it is not working in IE, it is not working in the popup window which i sreally fustrating

Comment: Try changing the browser options..I hope if u're using jquery will resolve this issue